# My finder doesn't show thumbnails anymore

Tags: finder, preview

My finder doesn't show thumbnails anymore, but simply spins indefinitely in the preview pane. This has been the case for a couple of months now and my productivity is suffering. I've looked around for solutions but nothing has worked, including deleting the com.apple.finder.plist file....

Can anyone help me restore this functionality?

Update: I rebooted in safe mode, and in safe mode the previews appear. When I reboot again in normal mode I have the problem. Not sure what to make of this or what might be getting in the way of this functionality.

[image]

Comment: I'd start by removing any 3rd party quicklook plugins, in `~/Library/QuickLook` or `/Library/QuickLook`

Comment: For what it's worth, an update to the OS seems to have resolved the issue